# Create App button is not generating the app, stuck on spinner

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to create a REST app, but when I go to My Apps and click on the Create App button, I get a spinner and a "We'll be right with you message" and it just stays like that. I went away, returned 10 minutes later and it was still showing the animation. Has anyone had any similar issues? How long does it take for the system to create the app? Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that you didn't get an answer on this: but if you see this spinner at anytime it's because PayPal is either updating the developer portal or they're having issues with it and fixing it. Next time you experience that [check here](https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/search?eventSearchType=PayPalSiteStatus) as it may help you.